# Exit code of pyspark job

Tags: pyspark

I'm launching a pyspark job like this:

`spark-submit --master yarn script.py`

The exit code here is always 0, even when the script exits with sys.exit(1)

Is there any way of detecting that it ran successfully?

Comment: did u solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the return code of the submit job. You should check the job status. A way to do it is using [Spark REST Api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).